# Map like structure in C: use int and struct to determine a value

Tags: c, dictionary, indexing, struct

I used to code in C++ and now I try to program in C.

Assume I have defined a struct

```
struct point{
    int x;
    int y;
}
```

Is there any data structure `A` in `c` that can support the following functionality:
Given two integers, say `i` and `j`, and two points, say `p1` and `p2`.
`A[i][j][p1][p2]` can uniquely determine a value.

It sounds like a 4-d array. However, indexes are no longer a int, but user-defined `struct`.

Comment: Why not just create a hashing function for your points and use that as an index?

Comment: There is no fancy data structure in C. You have to reinvent the wheel for yourself or go back to C++ !

Comment: There is nothing like this in C. You can't define operators in C. The closest thing you can have is a custom hash function that you use to index into an array, or something similar. The point is: you are pretty much tied to built-in types and have to invent everything yourself.

Comment: It looks like a *six*-dimensional array of sorts...

Comment: As others have said: Either go looking for "hashtable code in C", or  look up the basics of hashtables and implement one de novo. It isn't that difficult; I've implemented them several times. The main difference from the user's point of view will be that rather than saying `myHashTable.put(key,value)` you'll need to say `putToHashTable(myHashTable,key,value)` and so on. (Unless you want to really reinvent OO and start building method dispatch into your objects -- which is possible but overkill for this simple case.)

Answer (score 57, accepted):

You'll probably have to make your own structure.  *The C Programming Language by Kernighan and Ritchie* has an example of making an associate map in c, and what I'll detail below is based on what I remember from that.

Basically you'll need a struct **Map** that contains struct **Key** and struct **Value**.

```
struct Map {
    struct Key key;
    struct Value value;
};
```

struct **Key** contains elements that determine the value (in your case 2 points and 2 ints)

```
struct Key {
    struct point p1;
    struct point p2;
    int i;
    int j;
};
```

struct **Value** is whatever you want your key to point to (you didn't say)

You now have a struct **Map** that associates your four inputs with a value, but a single map isn't that useful.  You're going to want a whole array of them.

```
struct Map map[SIZE_OF_MAP];
```

If you don't want to linearly search the array for the **Map** struct you're looking for, you can make a hashing function that will bring you directly to it.  Just define a function that takes the key and uses its value to assign it an index in the array.  Use the hash to place the **Map** in the array and retrieve it from the array. (Note: I'm unsure if this is a correct example of hashing, please correct if this is completely wrong)

```
int get_hash(Key *key)
{
    int result;
    /* combine all inputs in some way */
    result = key->i * key->i + (key->p1.x * key->p1.x) - (key->p2.x * key->p2.x)
    /* make sure result isn't out of bounds of the array */
    return (result % SIZE_OF_MAP);
}
```

If you use the hashing function you'll have to consider collisions (what happens when two keys give the same result for **get_hash**).  When you use your array of Maps you'll need some form of collision resolution.

Answer (score 0):

I've been actively engaged in C++ and C programming for over a year. Lately, I've been intrigued by the idea of implementing a map-like structure in C, and I've come across an approach to tackle this challenge. The strategy involves utilizing a set of Binary Search Trees (BST) for creating a map structure:

```
struct Map{ struct Tree **t; };
```

In this method, a tree is defined as follows:

```
struct Pair{
    char *first;
    int second;
};
struct Pair *make_pair(char *a,int b){
struct Pair *x=(struct Pair *)malloc(sizeof(struct Pair));
x->first=strdup(a);
x->second=b;
return x;
};
struct Nod{
struct Pair *val;
struct Nod *dr,*st;
};
struct Tree{
struct Nod *top;
};
```

Moreover, there is a need for a make_hash function to generate a hash for a char* and a compare function for "comparing" two "strings":

```
//create the hash
int make_hash(char *s,int size){
//use unsigned long long because it starts from 0 after going past the limit.
unsigned long long hash=5813;
for(int i=0;s[i];i++) hash=hash*33+s[i];
return (hash%size);
};
//compare two "strings"
//note: my compare function returns -1 if both "strings" are equal 
int compare(char *a,char *b){
int i=0,x=0;
for(;a[i]&&b[i];i++){
    if(b[i]>a[i]) return 0;
    if(b[i]==a[i])x++;
}
if(a[i]&&!b[i])
return 1;
if(!a[i]&&b[i])
return 0;
if(!a[i]&&!b[i]&&x==i)
return -1;
};
```

Finally, the implementation requires functions for adding and finding a char* and its corresponding value in our program:

```
void addtotree(struct Tree *t,char *s,int val){
if(!t->top){
    t->top=(struct Nod *)malloc(sizeof(struct Nod));
    t->top->val=make_pair(s,val);
    t->top->st=NULL;
    t->top->dr=NULL;
    return;
}
struct Nod *nod=t->top;
while(nod){
    int x=compare(s,nod->val->first);
    if(x==1){
        if(nod->dr){
            nod=nod->dr;
        }
        else{
            nod->dr=(struct Nod *)malloc(sizeof(struct Nod));
            nod->dr->val=make_pair(s,val);
            nod->dr->dr=NULL;
            nod->dr->st=NULL;
            return;
        }
    }
    else if(x==0){
        if(nod->st){
            nod=nod->st;
        }
        else{
            nod->st=(struct Nod *)malloc(sizeof(struct Nod));
            nod->st->val=make_pair(s,val);
            nod->st->dr=NULL;
            nod->st->st=NULL;
            return;
        }
    }
    else if(x==-1){
        nod->val->second=val;
        return;
    }
}
}
struct Nod *findtotree(struct Tree *t,char *s){
struct Nod *nod=t->top;
while(nod){
    int x=compare(s,nod->val->first);
    if(x==1) nod=nod->dr;
    else if(x==0) nod=nod->st;
    else return nod;
}
return NULL;
};
void add(struct Map *m,char *s,int val){
int hash=make_hash(s,m->size);
if(!m->t[hash]){
    m->t[hash]=(struct Tree *)malloc(sizeof(struct Tree));
    m->t[hash]->top=NULL;
}
addtotree(m->t[hash],s,val);
};
int find(struct Map *m,char *s){
int hash=make_hash(s,m->size);
if(!m->t[hash]) return 0;
struct Nod *nod=findtotree(m->t[hash],s);
if(!nod) return 0;
return nod->val->second;
};
```

It's worth noting that there is room for improvement in this map implementation. With that in mind, let me now consolidate all the components:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
struct Pair{
    char *first;
    int second;
};
struct Pair *make_pair(char *a,int b){
    struct Pair *x=(struct Pair *)malloc(sizeof(struct Pair));
    x->first=strdup(a);
    x->second=b;
    return x;
};
int make_hash(char *s,int size){
    unsigned long long hash=5813;
    for(int i=0;s[i];i++) hash=hash*33+s[i];
    return (hash%size);
};
struct Nod{
    struct Pair *val;
    struct Nod *dr,*st;
};
struct Tree{
    struct Nod *top;
};
int compare(char *a,char *b){
    int i=0,x=0;
    for(;a[i]&&b[i];i++){
        if(b[i]>a[i]) return 0;
        if(b[i]==a[i])x++;
    }
    if(a[i]&&!b[i])
    return 1;
    if(!a[i]&&b[i])
    return 0;
    if(!a[i]&&!b[i]&&x==i)
    return -1;
};
void addtotree(struct Tree *t,char *s,int val){
    if(!t->top){
        t->top=(struct Nod *)malloc(sizeof(struct Nod));
        t->top->val=make_pair(s,val);
        t->top->st=NULL;
        t->top->dr=NULL;
        return;
    }
    struct Nod *nod=t->top;
    while(nod){
        int x=compare(s,nod->val->first);
        if(x==1){
            if(nod->dr){
                nod=nod->dr;
            }
            else{
                nod->dr=(struct Nod *)malloc(sizeof(struct Nod));
                nod->dr->val=make_pair(s,val);
                nod->dr->dr=NULL;
                nod->dr->st=NULL;
                return;
            }
        }
        else if(x==0){
            if(nod->st){
                nod=nod->st;
            }
            else{
                nod->st=(struct Nod *)malloc(sizeof(struct Nod));
                nod->st->val=make_pair(s,val);
                nod->st->dr=NULL;
                nod->st->st=NULL;
                return;
            }
        }
        else if(x==-1){
            nod->val->second=val;
            return;
        }
    }
}
struct Nod *findtotree(struct Tree *t,char *s){
    struct Nod *nod=t->top;
    while(nod){
        int x=compare(s,nod->val->first);
        if(x==1) nod=nod->dr;
        else if(x==0) nod=nod->st;
        else return nod;
    }
    return NULL;
};
struct Map{
struct Tree **t;
int size;
};
struct Map *createMap(int size){
    struct Map *m=(struct Map *)malloc(sizeof(struct Map));
    m->size=size;
    m->t=(struct Tree **)calloc(size,sizeof(struct Tree *));
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++) m->t[i]=NULL;
    return m;
};
void add(struct Map *m,char *s,int val){
    int hash=make_hash(s,m->size);
    if(!m->t[hash]){
        m->t[hash]=(struct Tree *)malloc(sizeof(struct Tree));
        m->t[hash]->top=NULL;
    }
    addtotree(m->t[hash],s,val);
    };
    int find(struct Map *m,char *s){
        int hash=make_hash(s,m->size);
        if(!m->t[hash]) return 0;
        struct Nod *nod=findtotree(m->t[hash],s);
        if(!nod) return 0;
        return nod->val->second;
    };
```

Comment: Where do all these strings (or “strings”) come from?

Comment: Well I defined a "string" a to be char *a, having in sight the fact that there are no strings in C, although there is the library <string.h>.

Comment: OK, and who creates those strings?

Comment: Unfortunately, as there are no predefined strings, you should create your own using malloc.
Example: _char* string=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*string_size))_ where string_size is an integer.
If you are interested, I used **strdup** in **make_pair** so it it possible to use the same pointer for different values (changing the value and then reuse it).
If I am not clear enough, I might as well explain that I used **strdup** with the intention of making sure that _make_pair(s,2)_ and make_pair(s,4) have different "string" pointers.

Comment: The mechanisms for making strings are well known.  None of that explains how the `struct point` data is ever involved.