# query parameter preserve as json

Tags: c, json, url, rest, cjson

I'm trying to store API request query parameters in JSON format, in a way that preserves the inferred original types of the parameters' values. I do this without knowing what these APIs look like beforehand.
The code below deals with each query argument (delimited by &) one by one.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < url_arg_cnt; i++) {
        const http_arg_t *arg = http_get_arg(http_info, i);
        if (cJSON_GetObjectItem(query, arg->name.p) == NULL) {
            // Currently just treating as a string.
            cJSON_AddItemToObject(query, arg->name.p, cJSON_CreateString(arg->value.p));
            SLOG_INFO("name:value is %s:%s\n", arg->name.p, arg->value.p);
        } else {
            //duplicate key.
        }
```

With the above code, for input

```
?start=0&count=2&format=policyid|second&id%5Bkey1%5D=1&id[key2]=2&object=%7Bone:1,two:2%7D&nested[][foo]=1&nested[][bar]=2
```

I get these prints:

```
name:value is start:0
name:value is count:2
name:value is format:policyid|second
name:value is id[key1]:1
name:value is id[key2]:2
name:value is object:{one:1, two:2}
name:value is nested[][foo]:1
name:value is nested[][bar]:2
```

According to this document and other places I've researched,
https://swagger.io/docs/specification/serialization/

There is no consensus on how the query parameters are passed, therefore no guarantee what I could encounter here. So my goal is to support as many variations as possible.
These possibilities seem to be the most common:

Arrays:

```
?x = 1,2,3

?x=1&x=2&x=3

?x=1%202%203

?x=1|2|3

?x[]=1&x[]=2
```

String:

```
?x=1
```

Object, could be nested:

```
?x[key1]=1&x[key2]=2

?x=%7Bkey1:1,key2:2%7D

?x[][foo]=1&x[][bar]=2

?fields[articles]=title,body&fields[people]=name

?x[0][foo]=bar&x[1][bar]=baz
```

Any ideas how to best go about this? Basically for these query parameters I want to aggregate ('exploded') arguments that belong together and save to ***query*** proper intended json objects. Line in question:

```
cJSON_AddItemToObject(query, arg->name.p, cJSON_CreateString(arg->value.p));
```

Comment: You want triple curly brackets - double to get an actual `{` in the output, plus a single to perform the actual variable substitution.

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking, or maybe said differently what you expect to learn from answers.  It seems like you figured out out to parse one version.  Are you asking how to structure the code to parse the different options?  Are you trying to normalize each (array, string, object) into a standard type (i.e. a data modeling question)?  Are you trying to store the parsed values so you can restore the original string? etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently ran into the same issue and will share some wisdom gained from the episode.
I'm assuming you are implementing this on a MITM device (web firewall, etc.).
As notedly in the question, there is no consensus in how the query parameters are passed. Not one standard or a set of rules that govern this -- in fact, any server may implement its own syntax, as long as the syntax is supported by the server code. The best one can do is to 1) decide what query parameter forms to support (do the best you can, maybe as many as possible) and 2) support only those forms, treat the rest (ones not supported) as String values, like your current code does.

It's not worth it to fret too much about the accuracy of the preservation/inference of type in question, or formalizing/generalizing it for a heavyweight solution because 1) the arbitrariness of syntax you may encounter (not necessarily conforming to any standard, web servers can really do whatever they want, therefore the query parameters often don't conform to the, say, swagger standard referenced) and 2) looking at the query parameters only gives you so much information -- the benefit/value of implementing anything more than vague approximations (per rules defined by yourself, as stated before) is hard to be seen. Think about even the simplest of cases, how vague they can be: you sorta have to pretend in the x=something&x=something exploded case, arrays have to have at least two elements. If only one element -- x=something -- you treat it as a string, for how else do you know whether it's an array or a string? How about the x=1 case, is 1 a string or a number, the original / intended type? Also, how about x=foo&y=1 | 2 | 3? or when you see "1, 2, 3", with spaces? Are the spaces supposed to be ignored, are they array delimiters themselves, or are they actually a part of the array elements. Finally, how do you even know the intended string is not "1 | 2 | 3" itself, meaning it's not an array!

So the best one can do in parsing these strings and trying to support/ infer all these variations (different rules) is to define ones own rules (what one is okay/happy with) and support only those.

Answer (score 2):

#### Converting the URI query to JSON

This post will provide more generic (canonical) approach toward the problem of extraction of the variables from the URI string.

The query is defined across several descriptive standards (RFCs and specifications), so tho have canonical approach, we need to use the specifications to create a normalized form of the query before we can build the object.

#### TL;DR

To assure that we can be implement the specifications with the ability to cater for future extensions, the algorithm to convert the query to JSON should be separated in steps, each one gradually building the normalized form of the query, before it can be converted to JSON object. To do so, we need the following steps:

- Extract the query from the URI
- Split to `key=value`
- Normalize the `key` (build the object hierarchy)
- Normalize the `value` (populate the object attributes and build the attribute arrays)
- Build JSON object based on the normalized `key=value`

Such separation of the steps will allow much easier adoption of future changes in the specifications. The parsing of the values can be done with RegEx or with a parser (BNF, PEG, etc.).

#### Conversion steps

1. First thing to be done is to extract the query string from the URI. This is described in the [RFC3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986) and will be explained in it's own section **Extracting the query string**. The extraction of the query segment, as we will see later, can be easily done with RegEx.
2. After query string is extracted from the URI, one needs to interpret the information conveyed by the query. As we will see below, the query has a very loose definition in the [RFC3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986), and the case where the query is conveying variables is further elaborated in [RFC6570](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6570). During the extraction, the algorithm should extract the values (that are in form of `key=value`) and store them in a map structure (one approach would be to use strict as described in following [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21958788/2816703). The section **Interpreting the query string** provides overview of the process.
3. After the variables are separated and placed in form of `key=value`, next stage is to normalize the `key`. Proper interpretation of the `key` will allow us to build the hierarchical structure of the JSON object from the `key=value` structure. The [RFC6570](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6570) is not providing much information on how the `key` can be normalized, however the [OpenAPI specification](https://swagger.io/specification/) provides a good information how to handle different types of `key`. The normalization  will be further elaborated in section **Normalizing the key**
4. Next we need to normalize the variables by continuing to build on the [RFC6570](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6570) which defines the types of the variables in several levels. This will be further elaborated in section **Normalizing the value**
5. Final stage is to build the JSON object with `cJSON_AddItemToObject(query, name, cJSON_CreateString(value));`. More details will be discussed in the **Building the JSON Object** section.

During implementation, some of the steps can be merged to a single step to optimize the implementation.

#### Extracting the query string

The [RFC3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986) which is the main descriptive standard that is governing the URI is defining the URI as:

```
URI         = scheme ":" hier-part [ "?" query ] [ "#" fragment ]
```

The `query` part is defined in the section 3.4 of the RFC as the segment of the URI such as:

> ... The query component is indicated by the first question
> mark ("?") character and terminated by a number sign ("#") character
> or by the end of the URI. ...

The formal syntax of the `query` segment is defined as:

```
query         = *( pchar / "/" / "?" )
pchar         = unreserved / pct-encoded / sub-delims / ":" / "@"
unreserved    = ALPHA / DIGIT / "-" / "." / "_" / "~"
pct-encoded   = "%" HEXDIG HEXDIG
sub-delims    = "!" / "$" / "&" / "'" / "(" / ")"
                 / "*" / "+" / "," / ";" / "="
```

This means that the `query` can contain more instances of `?` and `/` before the `#` is met. Actually, as long as the characters after first occurrence of the`?` are in the set of characters that do not have special meaning, everything that is found until first `#` is encountered is the `query`.

At the same time, this also implies that the sub-delimiter `&`, as well as the `?` has no special meaning according to this RFC when is encountered inside the query string, as long as it's in the proper form and position in the `URI`. This implies that each implementation can define its own structure. The language of RFC in chapter 3.4 confirms such implications by leaving space for other interpretations by using `often` instead of `always`

> ... However, as query components
> are often used to carry identifying information in the form of
> "key=value" pairs ...

In addition, the RFC also provides the following RegEx that can be used to extract the query part from the URI:

```
regex   : ^(([^:/?#]+):)?(//([^/?#]*))?([^?#]*)(\?([^#]*))?(#(.*))?
segments:   12            3  4          5       6  7        8 9
```

Where the capture #7 is the query from the URI.

The easiest approach for extracting the query, provided that we are not interested in the remaining parts of the URI, is to use the RegEx to split the URI and extract the query string that will not contain the leading `?` nor the terminating `#`.

This RFC3986 is further extended with the [RFC3987](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3987) in order to cover the international characters, however the RegEx defined by the RFC3986 remains valid

#### Extracting variables from the query string

To decompose the query string to `key=value` pairs, we need to do reverse engineering of the [RFC6570](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6570) which establishes a descriptive standard for the expansion of the variables and constructing the valid `query`. As the RFC is stating

> ... A URI Template provides both a structural description of a URI space
> and, when variable values are provided, machine-readable instructions
> on how to construct a URI corresponding to those values. ...

From the RFC, we can extract the following syntax for a variable in the query:

```
query         =  variable *( "&" variable )
variable      =  varname "=" varvalue

varvalue      = *( valchar / "[" / "] / "{" / "}" / "?" )

varname       =  varchar *( ["."] varchar )
varchar       =  ALPHA / DIGIT / "_" / pct-encoded

pct-encoded   = "%" HEXDIG HEXDIG
valchar       = unreserved / pct-encoded / vsub-delims / ":" / "@"
unreserved    = ALPHA / DIGIT / "-" / "." / "_" / "~"
vsub-delims   = "!" / "$" / "'" / "(" / ")"
                 / "*" / "+" / ","
```

The extraction can be performed with a parser that implements the above grammar, or by iterating over the query with the following RegEx and extracting the (`key`, `value`) pairs.

```
([\&](([^\&]*)\=([^\&]*)))
```

In case we use RegEx, note that in previous section we had omitted the "?" at the start of the query and "#" at the end, so we need don't need to handle this characters in the separation of the variables.

#### Normalizing the key

There descriptive standard [RFC6570](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6570) provides generic rules of the format of the key, the RFC is not helping much when it comes to the rules for the interpretation of the key when an object is constructed. Some of the specifications such as the [OpenAPI specification](https://swagger.io/specification/), [JSON API Specification](https://jsonapi.org/format/#fetching-sparse-fieldsets)), etc. can help with the interpretation, but they are not providing the full set of rules, rather a subset. To make the things wort, some of the SDKs (ex. PHP SDK) have its own rules for building the keys.

In such situation, the best approach is to create a hierarchical rules for key normalization that will convert the key to a unified format, similar to [json path dot notation](https://support.smartbear.com/alertsite/docs/monitors/api/endpoint/jsonpath.html). The hierarchical rules will allow us to control how the ambiguous situations (in case of collisions between specifications), but controlling the order of the rules. The json path notation will allow us to build the object in the final step without the necessity to have proper order of the `key=value` pairs.

Following is the grammar of the normalized format:

```
key      = sub-key *("." sub-key )
sub-key  = name [ ("[" index "]") ]
name     = *( varchar )
index    = NONZERO-DIGIT *( DIGIT )
```

This grammar will allow for keys such as `foo`, `foo.baz`, `foo[0].baz`, `foo.baz[0]`, `foo.bar.baz` etc.

Following are a good starting point to set of rules and the transformation

1. Flat key (`key` -> `key`)
2. Attribute key (`key.atr` -> `key.atr`)
3. Array key (`key[]` -> `key[0]`)
4. Object Array key (`key[attribute]` -> `key.attribute`), (`key[][attribute]` -> `key[0].attribute`), (`key[attribute][]` -> `key.attribute[0]`)

More rules can be added to address special cases. During the transformation, the algorithm should pass from the most specific rules (the bottom rules) to the most generic rules and try to find a full match. If a full match if found, the key will be overwritten with the normal form and the remaining rules will be skipped.

#### Normalizing the value

Similar to the normalization of the key, the value should also be normalized in cases where the value represents a list. We will need to convert the value from the arbitrary list format to the `form` format (coma separated list) which is defined by the following grammar:

```
value        = singe-value *( "," singe-value ) 
singe-value  = *( unreserved / pct-encoded )
```

This grammar will allow us the value to take form `a`, `a,b`, `a,b,c`, etc.

Extracting the list of the values from the value string can be done with splitting the string by the valid delimiters (",",";","|", etc.) and producing the list in a normalized form.

#### Building the JSON Object

Once the keys and the values are normalized, converting the flat list (the map structure) to a JSON Object can be done by a singe pass trough all of the keys in the list. The normalized format of the key will help us, since the key conveys the whole information about his hierarchy in the object, so even if we had not encountered some of the intermediate attributes, we are able to build the object.

Similar, we can recognize if the value of the attribute should be a flat string or an array from the  variable itself, so here as well, no additional information is required to create the proper representation.

#### Alternative approach

As alternative approach, we can construct a full grammar that will create the AST (abstract syntax tree), and use the tree to produce the JSON object, however due to the multiple variations of the formats and ability to have future extensions, this approach will be less flexible.

#### Useful links

- The grammar in the text is following [ABNF grammar rules](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5234)
- [JSON Path](https://support.smartbear.com/alertsite/docs/monitors/api/endpoint/jsonpath.html)
- [GNU Bison](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/) is example of BNF parser
- [C PEG parser library](https://www.piumarta.com/software/peg/) is example of PEG parser